# Bash commands in for loop don't execute

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, cp

I have a script that loops through all .ooutline files in my directory and should copy them to another folder.

```
for file in *.ooutline; do
   echo cp  \'"$file"\' "$HOME"/Omnipresence/outlines3/
done
```

Now, when I echo the script and run it like so:

```
./bcpy.sh > out1.sh
```

the echo produces perfect cp statements, and after a chmod a+x I can run out1.sh as a batch script. I get cp statements like this:

```
cp 'savethecat steps.ooutline' /Users/michaelisbell/Omnipresence/outlines3/
cp 'steps 8 28.ooutline' /Users/michaelisbell/Omnipresence/outlines3/
cp 'story points 3 2.ooutline' /Users/michaelisbell/Omnipresence/outlines3/
cp 'story points 3.ooutline' /Users/michaelisbell/Omnipresence/outlines3/
```

and these execute perfectly in the out1.sh file.

They do not, however execute in the bcpy.sh file, after I remove the echo. I get this error:

```
cp: 'savethecat steps.ooutline': No such file or directory
cp: 'steps 8 28.ooutline': No such file or directory
cp: 'story points 3 2.ooutline': No such file or directory
cp: 'story points 3.ooutline': No such file or directory
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, and why my commands aren't executing in the bcpy2.sh script as I expect them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the spaces in your file names.

If you do the quoting right, you don't have to worry about it. It's nonsense to echo a `cp` command to a file and execute from that, when you can do it directly.

You can just

`for file in *.ooutline; do
   cp  "$file" "$HOME"/Omnipresence/outlines3/
done`

from the command line directly, or put the above in a bcpy.sh file with a first line
of `#!/bin/bash` and make bcpy.sh executable with `chmod +x bcpy/sh` and run it 
as `./bcpy.sh` next.

Comment: you were correct. I hadn't added the #!/bin/bash line. Once I added it, and removed the unnecessary single quotes, the script ran smoothly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @johnrubythecat Glad I could help. Tasks like this I do almost daily. I usually just do it on the command line directly.

Comment: `#!#!/bin/bash
 for file in *.ooutline; do

 mv "$file" "$(echo  $file | cut -d'.' -f 1)"


 done`

Comment: I was able to make this work, but it took me a few hours of fiddling. I have to admit, after reading the web pages and the o'reilly books, while I understand that " expands variables and ' doesn't, I don't really understand why mv needs me to put quotes around variables, while variable assignment doesn't seem to require it. if I echo the mv result here, I get filenames with spaces with no quotes around them, and the command runs fine--except that would never work on the command line. So I admit I am baffled the echo output is misleading and seems to output opposite of what's really happening.

Comment: otoh I finally figured out that 'cut' is a 'split' command lol.

Comment: @johnrubythecat On the command line you leave off the #! line, of course. No double #!#!, which is also wrong.

Comment: @johnrubythecat just enter `for file in *.ooutline; do mv "$file" destination_dir; done` . if you do `echo $file` without quotes, a name with spaces is interpreted as several words but `cut -d'.' -f1` then splits on the '.' character, so you get every thing before the first . *but as several words*. So the mv command is confused as it will get more than two arguments and the last one is probably not   a directory.